# Find direct known subclasses with type parameter in macro

Tags: scala

In short, I need a macro that for a given sealed trait finds all subtypes.

Suppose I have the following hierarchy:

```scala
sealed trait T[A]
case class C[A]() extends T[A]
```

Now, in my macro, I have the `WeakTypeTag` for e.g. `T[String]`.
Using `.asClass.knownDirectSubclasses`, I can find `C[A]`, but I don't see a good way to arrive at type `C[String]`. I've experimented with `.substituteTypes(..., ...)` but without success.

Comment: `knownDirectSubclasses` doesn't work in all the cases anyway

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out.

The answer is using `appliedType(..., ...)` included in `import c.universe._`.